# Why does Xamarin Forms Picker has transparent selector modal?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have create a new view in order to be sure the opacity is not applied for some resource in my app, but for some reason it is not working in a clean enviroment neither.

I have checked the XF documentation and the modal with all the items should render in a solid color.

[image: Xamarin Forms Picker - with transparency above and below the items]

[image]

Comment: what's the app's theme? It'll be in the manifest or if you don't set it there it will be the device default in the settings somewhere. Also, could you check what it looks like with a lime green background? It might just be black on black and you think it's transparent

Comment: yes, I have not set a theme. I am researching how to do that

Comment: I am trying to set a theme, but the app does not use this!

Comment: I tested this app on my Samsung S6 and works fine, so maybe the emulator has some default theme with this issue. Thanks anyway @Slepz

Answer (score 0):

I have found the emulator was rendering a wrong modal for the picker, maybe it is caused by the default theme on the emulator. I have tested the app on a real device and seems to be ok.